# How could I detect an Intent with a context ? (node.js SDK for Dialogflow API V2)

Tags: node.js, nlp, dialogflow-es

How could I detect an Intent with a context ?

I defined an Intent "Book" with an input Context "Activity", then trained my bot with "Book this activity in my schedule".
I don't want to use dialog flow to manage context flow because it may evolve from other inputs in my app. So I want pass it as a parameter for each intent detection.
I use node.js SDK for Dialogflow API V2.

I precise it works fine with REST API v1 ... I think i'm stuck with API v2 Contexts :)
I'm looking to do exactly the same as the following code with API v2

```
//code below is working fine
import apiai from 'apiai';// Dialogflow SDK v1
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
const sessionId = uuidv4();
const api = apiai('myToken');
const lang = 'en-US';

  const request = api.textRequest('Book this activity in my schedule', {
    sessionId,
    lang,
    contexts : [{ name : 'activity' }],
  });

  request.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });

  request.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  request.end();
```

I didn't found documentation or exemple to do that except API documentation so I probably did something wrong

Whenever I pass a context as a queryParams or create a Context it don't work.
It also seems that context creation from API don't work at all.

```
import dialogflow from 'dialogflow';//Dialogflow SDK v2
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
const projectId = 'myID';
const sessionId = uuidv4();
const languageCode = 'en-US';
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
const contextClient = new dialogflow.ContextsClient();
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

...
```

First try returned my Default Fallback Intent  :

```
const request = {
    session     : sessionPath,
    queryParams : {
      context : {
        parent : sessionPath,
        name   : contextClient.contextPath(
          projectId,
          sessionId,
          'activity'
        ),
      },
    },
    queryInput : {
      text : {
        text         : 'Book this activity in my schedule',
        languageCode : languageCode,
      },
    },
  };

sessionClient.detectIntent(request)
    .then(responses => {
      const result = responses[0].queryResult;
      if (result.intent) {
        console.log(result.intent.displayName);
      } else {
        console.log('  No intent matched.');
      }
    });
```

Second try returned my Default Fallback Intent  :

```
contextClient
    .createContext({
      parent  : sessionPath,
      context : {
        name : contextClient.contextPath(
          projectId,
          sessionId,
          'activity'
        ),
      },
    })
    .then(() => contextClient.listContexts({ parent : sessionPath }))
    .then(contexts => {
      console.log(contexts);//returned an empty list
      return sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    }).then(responses => {
      const result = responses[0].queryResult;
      if (result.intent) {
        console.log(result.intent.displayName);
      } else {
        console.log('  No intent matched.');
      }
    });
```

Anybody see what's wrong with it ?
Help needed :)

Comment: did u manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue.
Found that I need to send "lifespanCount" greated than 0.

```
{
    "session": "projects\/verifier-26084\/agent\/sessions\/1gg5b76c37f7111b",
    "queryParams":
    {
        "contexts": [
        {
            "name": "projects\/verifier-26084\/agent\/sessions\/1gg5b76c37f7111b\/contexts\/ask-children",
            "lifespanCount": 1
        }]
    },
    "queryInput":
    {
        "text":
        {
            "text": "\u0442\u0440\u0438",
            "languageCode": "ru-RU"
        }
    }
}
```